# Java forceful Garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is it possible to call the java garbage collector forcefully ? 
I have a java multi threaded application and I want to minimize  the time frequency which java garbage collector executes on that application.

Comment: No, it can't be forced.

Comment: In my opinion, you should first analyze the current application using profiler/GC logging etc. and get statistics, if needed fine tune your VM arguments related to garbage collection.

Comment: Invoking it directly will cause the GC to occur more often. The best way to reduce the impact of GC is to create less garbage in the first place, giving it less to do, less often.

Answer (score 0):

There is System.gc();
However, don't use it. It is not sure that a gc will actually be triggered.

Instead, configure your runtime to give you you the expected gc. check the documentation for the JRE you are using, since this is highly implementation specific.

Answer (score 0):

System.gc() is used to invoke the garbage collector. It will attempt to free the memory that are occupied by the discarded objects. However System.gc() call comes with a disclaimer that invocation of the garbage collector is not guaranteed.